# Code access to external urls

Tags: c#

I have code that uses process class to sign code with a verisign signature.

So basically it uses command line cmd. Now this all used to work but recently (maybe due to malware), it fails at the timestamping stage. Pretty sure this is because it is no longer able to access the verisign external url in order to time stamp.

I have tried the same command from command manually and the result is the same. I have a proxy configured in IE which is necessary for external web access but I assume when I'm using cmd for e.g. it's not derived from IE settings?

Comment: First clear up the malware and make your sever SECURE...

Comment: I have, malware is gone and everything works as expected.

Comment: Should add that everyhing works as expected apart from my intial post, I did run malware remover before I posted.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like your IE proxy settings got messed up. Malware can do that. Go into IE, then Internet Options (it's different depending on version of IE and Windows). Once in there, hunt down proxy settings and turn them off. I'd guess they are currently enabled.

Also, timestamping will fail if the certificate expired. Did it expire?

Comment: HI Nathanial,
I don't have access to the same PC anymore but it did work on other pcs. I did also check my proxy settings it did seem fine. However, I'm unable to look into the issue further since I don't have access to the PC. Thanks for your response.